# Cartesian graphing how in gnumeric or excel

Tags: excel, graph, gnumeric

I'm not so great with spreadsheets, formulas, etc. so be gentle ; )
I have a date column of year/months and I want the number of rows in the spreadsheet out put as function of months where one axis is months and the other axis is frequency that certain rows occur in certain months.
I could always just use a column of just months but I was unable to format the cells like that.
I'm looking for a linear output like a Cartesian set up of positive values.
Other option is output as cells with months and number of occurrences per month

Answer (score 0):

Is this the sort of thing you're after?

[image]

**Formulae:**

Month `=RIGHT(A2,2)`

Year `=LEFT(A2,4)`

MonthName `=TEXT(DATE(C2,B2,1),"MMMM")`

Months `hard-coded`

Count `=COUNTIF($D$2:$D$20,G2)`

Then Insert a PivotChart, with Axis as `Months` and Values as `Sum of Count`.